# Differences between program.cs and startup.cs in .NET 6.0 Core Web API Project

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm currently working on a university project where I'm building a .NET 6.0 Core web API using Visual Studio. According to the project rubric, I need to make changes to the "startup.cs file". However, in my project, I only see a "program.cs" file. I'm aware that in .NET 6.0, there have been some changes to the project structure. Could someone please clarify if the "program.cs" file has replaced the "startup.cs" file in .NET 6.0, or am I missing something important? Any insights or guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

I've been conducting research to determine whether utilizing the "program.cs" file is the appropriate approach for my situation. I wanted to explore if making adjustments to this file aligns with the recommended practices for configuring a .NET 6.0 Core web API project.